# Is it true that in Objective-C, if a method is not alloc, new, or copy, then you don't do the release and it is supposedly in the autorelease pool?

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

It seems that there is a standard convention that in Objective-C, if a method is `alloc`, `new`, or `copy`, then: you now have the ownership to the new object, and so you are supposed to release it using `[obj release]` (suppose this is not ARC).

If, however, the method to get a new instance is by those "convenience methods", such as in `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100]`, since it is not `alloc`, `new`, or `copy`, so the new object, by convention, is in the autorelease pool, and you never worry about releasing it?

Comment: Not everything is put in the autorelease pool.

Comment: if it is not in the autorelease pool, then how can the memory that the convenience methods claimed by `alloc` be freed?

Comment: All objects returned by convenience/factory methods like arrayWithCapacity are in the autorelease pool. And all your own methods should always return autoreleased objects (that is, retained once, then autoreleased), unless, of course, for the exceptions mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you didn't allocate the object, you don't need to release it. (under your assumptions of course)

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is true.  Here is the [Objective-C reference that defines the rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) (which is more of a convention, however the clang static analyzer will object if you don't follow the convention).

Comment: And the same goes for Core Foundation pseudo-object creation: if a function has "copy" or "create" in its name, you need to manually release the returned object, otherwise not.